# How to print the data in ascending order?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df['2020-01': '2020-02']['Close'].head(50)
```

Results:

```
Date
2020-02-29 23:00:00    217.35
2020-02-29 22:00:00    222.93
2020-02-29 21:00:00    223.59
2020-02-29 20:00:00    224.81
2020-02-29 19:00:00    225.56
2020-02-29 18:00:00    225.05
2020-02-29 17:00:00    225.37
2020-02-29 16:00:00    222.94
2020-02-29 15:00:00    225.43
2020-02-29 14:00:00    223.31
.....
```

This data is being printed in a descending order, how can I print the same data in ascending order?

Answer (score 0):

you didnt provide which libraries have you tried to use it wall be easier to help you with a code snippet. But if i guess right you were using the head function of the pandas library in python.

1. If your dataframe is 50 rows long you can also use the `.tail(number_of_rows)` and it will reverse your answer but,
   ***NOTE***: it will only work if your dataframe is as long as the rows your entered in the `.head(number_of_rows)` function.
2. The second option is to sort the dataframe first using `sort_values(by=column_name, ascending=True)` and if its multiply columns the syntax is `sort_values(by=[column_name1, column_name2,...,column_namen], ascending=True)`.
   first exctract only the rows you want to see, in your example is the first 50 rows it will make the computation faster and will not show the uncessary data you didnt want to see in the first place.
   ***Tip:*** Create a copy of your data frame first so the the real dataframe object will not change during your work for further analysis.

I wouldve used the second option beacuse you might get huge dataframes when the first option will not work.

Comment: Hi @Mark Kapilyan thanks for the information I used the pandas library, forgot to use the tail function. I have a question though so we are talking about sorting the complete CSV file and changing it in inplace before picking the particular data?

Comment: @Indranil_Palit hey, i do not recommend sorting everything i would recommend sort everything if its your solution and its the direction you are headed. I would extract the rows that i need for my soultion and then sort them in the order i need, in your case it was the first 50 rows but it can be from xN to xY rows and after the extraction to sort them so it would be more efficient

Comment: Hi @Mark Kapilyan you're right, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create sample df
sample_df = {
     'Date': ["2020-02-29 23:00:00",  "2020-02-29 22:00:00", "2020-02-29 21:00:00", "2020-02-29 20:00:00", "2020-02-29 19:00:00"],
     'Close' : ["217.35", "222.93", "223.59", "224.81", "225.56"]
     }
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_df)

# Make Date as date column
sample_df['Date'] = sample_df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Then do the sorting:

```
# Sort DataFrame by date column
sample_df.sort_values(by='Date', inplace = True)
sample_df
```